# Elements of 100% width rendering <td> differently

Tags: html, css

I'm laying out a table (yes, for tabular data!) and I'm failing to understand how the widths of the table cells are being determined. For a `<table>` with 100% width and two empty `<td>` cells, each cell will take up half the space. Things start changing once different elements are added within the `<td>`s. However, the children elements of the `<td>`s all have width of 100%. I would not expect this to change the width of the cells, but it does.

For example, the two cells in the following code have different widths:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>100%</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input placeholder="other" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I collected a few other examples in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beej/Jqqd9/4/).

*My question(s)*:

1. Why is this happening (*e.g. why aren't the columns even?*)?
2. Can I maintain evenly sized cells regardless of their contents, even if I don't know how many columns there will be for a given table?

Comment: You applied the `width` to the inner `div` while it should be applied to the `td`. To have evenly sized cells regardless of their contents, you may have to use fixed table layout (table-layout:fixed), and handle the overflow content for the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are letting the browser determine the widths and it will collapse the smaller one to minimum size for the containing elements.  If you want to have everything being equal set `table-layout: fixed` on your table css.

This will divide the columns close to evenly for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jqqd9/6/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout

> In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is
>   determined as follows:
>
> 1. A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property sets the width for that column.
> 2. Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto'
>      for the 'width' property determines the width for that column. If
>      the cell spans more than one column, the width is divided over the
>      columns.
> 3. Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table
>      space (minus borders or cell spacing).

The default is auto which is found in this manner.

> Column widths are determined as follows:
>
> 1. Calculate the minimum content width (MCW) of each cell: the
>      formatted content may span any number of lines but may not overflow
>      the cell box. If the specified 'width' (W) of the cell is greater
>      than MCW, W is the minimum cell width. A value of 'auto' means that
>      MCW is the minimum cell width.
>      Also, calculate the "maximum" cell width of each cell: formatting
>      the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line
>      breaks occur.
> 2. For each column, determine a maximum and minimum column width from
>      the cells that span only that column. The minimum is that required
>      by the cell with the largest minimum cell width (or the column
>      'width', whichever is larger). The maximum is that required by the
>      cell with the largest maximum cell width (or the column 'width',
>      whichever is larger).
> 3. For each cell that spans more than one column, increase the minimum
>      widths of the columns it spans so that together, they are at least
>      as wide as the cell. Do the same for the maximum widths. If
>      possible, widen all spanned columns by approximately the same
>      amount.
> 4. For each column group element with a 'width' other than 'auto',
>      increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans, so that
>      together they are at least as wide as the column group's 'width'.

Comment: Thanks for the spec link! Good answer, and it helped with my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the `table-layout:fixed` CSS property to solve the issue,
here is the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/HWhp6/